# MySQL - Usage of 'Allow NULL'

Tags: mysql, null, schema

Does usage of NULL to fill empty cells on my tables make searches / queries faster?

For example is this

```
90  2   65  2011-04-08  NULL    NULL    
134 2   64  2011-04-13  NULL    07:00:00    
135 2   64  2011-04-13  NULL    07:00:00    
136 2   64  2011-04-13  NULL    22:45:00    
137 2   64  2011-04-14  NULL    19:30:00
```

better than

```
90  2   65  2011-04-08          
134 2   64  2011-04-13           07:00:00   
135 2   64  2011-04-13           07:00:00   
136 2   64  2011-04-13           22:45:00   
137 2   64  2011-04-14           19:30:00
```

If anyone could tell me any specific advantage to using NULL (performance, good practice, etc) that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using NULL over some other 'empty value' (such as 0 or an empty string) **will have no affect on performance** (except perhaps in the most pathologically devised cases). So, **please don't think about "performance" at all with NULL**. There are, however, good times to use NULL-able columns and bad times -- this depends upon the model, of course.

Comment: thanks @pst - i googled around but could not find a good answer to this - yours seems pretty good - would you like to add as an answer?

Comment: There will be better answers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a semantic difference.

- `NULL` means "value unknown or not applicable".

If this describes the data for that column, then use it.

- The empty string means "value known, and it's 'nothingness'".

If this describes the data for that column, then use it. Of course, this applies only to strings; it's unusual to have such a scenario for other data types, but usually for numeric fields a value of `0` would be appropriate here.

In short, it depends mostly on what your fields *mean*. Worry about performance and profiling later, when you know what data you're representing. (`NULL` vs `""` is never going to be your bottleneck, though.)

Comment: +1 Sometimes I wish there was an "I asked, but I didn't get a reply" value in SQL.

Comment: @pst: Sounds like `NULL` to me. Again, though, it depends on the model.

Comment: thanks @tomalak - the table in question is a data table, where users store all sorts of records, such as date, location, type of exercise, duration, etc. - not all fields will be mandatory, so there will be some blanks throughout the table - i wondered if they could negatively affect performance once this single table gets big with lots of users and records

Comment: @torr: No. They pretty much couldn't.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Consider the different states: 1) Didn't ask the napkin its name, because its a napkin and a name isn't required (NULL) 2) Asked the napkin its name, and it said it was the napkin with the-name-with-no-value ("") 3) Asked the napkin its name, but the napkin (being a napkin) didn't respond (--> ??? <--). Sometimes I really wish there was a difference between UNDEFINED/UNKNOWN (in SQL NULL has to try and fill both, depending upon model and definition of values. Because of index uniqueness issues an "empty sentinel" doesn't always work.)

Comment: @pst: I don't really follow that last bit. `NULL` != `NULL` so there are no index uniqueness issues in using it as a sentinel, albeit an "unknown" sentinel rather than an "empty" one.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal the SQL definition is vague on the matter. SQLite will allow duplicate NULL values in a *unique* column/index. Microsoft SQL Server, however, will not (duplicate NULL values in a unique column is a constraint violation). They are both conforming to the specification (just a different interpretation of it). I find the SQLite definition much more useful :-)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal The problem is if NULL is taken to be "unknown" *it can't also* represent "undefined". So an "undefined" value, say the string "" might be used. However, excluding the interpretation of NULL in unique indices, this "undefined value" still can only be a singleton in a unique column/index. I think Codd originally argued for another value along with NULL.

Comment: In almost every logical representation (take, for example, the IEEE floating point spec, cba to look up the number), `NULL != NULL`. If SQLite doesn't obey this, then it may be conforming to the SQL spec but IMO it's not conforming to fricking common sense.